# php echo and join mysqldatabase

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trolling the internet for the solution to my issue. I am teaching myself relationship databasing and trying to echo this on my webpage. but it is not echoing :(

please can a fresh pair of eyes take a look at my code and point me in the right direction.
many thanks

I have been trying to do a test run before editing for my own purposes

```
database: fault
table: user
collumns: id name course 
foreign key(fk_course)fault,course,id
table: course
Collumns: id coursename
```

Code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

//where statement in the sql syntax will select where in db to get infor, use AND to add another condition
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.name, course.coursename FROM 'user' INNER JOIN 'course' ON user.course = coursename.id"); //this creates a variable that selects the database

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Course</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['coursename'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: _"I have been trolling the internet for the solution to my issue."_ - Can't imagine that worked out too well.

Comment: You have enclosed table names by wrong quotes. That should be backticks, not quotes, i.e. ` table_name `, not 'table_name' - second case will be treated as string literal and causes syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SQL statment should look like this:

```
SELECT user.name,
       course.coursename
  FROM user INNER JOIN course ON user.course = course.id;
```

Use normal aposthropes for strings and the `ON` part should correctly match the fields.

Comment: thank you it works, i have been looking over this problem at the end of a days work and my tired eyes couldnt see the issue. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrote as

```
SELECT user.name, course.coursename FROM 'user' INNER JOIN 'course' ON user.course = coursename.id
```

Here table is course not coursename. 
Try this

```
SELECT user.name, course.coursename FROM user INNER JOIN course ON user.course = course.id
```

Comment: thank you it works, i have been looking over this problem at the end of a days work and my tired eyes couldnt see the issue. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
 require 'connection.php';

 //where statement in the sql syntax will select where in db to get infor, use AND to add another condition

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.name, course.coursename FROM 'user' INNER JOIN 'course' ON user.course = coursename.id"); //this creates a variable that selects the database

echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Course</th>  
</tr>";  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo "<tr>"; 
   echo "<td>"<?=$row['name'];?>"</td>";  
   echo "<td>" <?=$row['coursename'];?>"</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
}  
echo "</table>";
?> `
```